# unable to compile GLSL shaders on Qt 5.3 after Nvidia driver update

Tags: qt, opengl

I have some very basic openGL shader that used to compile but are not compiling anymore after a Nvidia driver update.
Every shader begins with following line:
    #version 150 core
     ....

I used to compile those shaders using QGLShaderProgram::addShaderFromSourceFile method

it is mentionned in documentation (http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglshaderprogram.html#writing-portable-shaders) that for reusability purpose, following preprocessor directive are added at the beginning of the shader

```
#define highp
#define mediump
#define lowp
```

However, since the driver update, I have a compilation error:

```
error C0204: version directive must be first statement and may not be repeated
```

and my shader source has become

```
#define highp
#define mediump
#define lowp
#version 150 core
 ....
```

So the issue is pretty simple to understand, however the fix is not so easy.
Is it a way to prevent Qt to had the #define?
What is the proper solution to deal with this issue (if possible without rewriting all my shader management code)

Comment: Can you please add the exact shader you're using, and the exact error log reported by `log()`, as well as anything printed on the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serious rendering issues with OpenGL 4.1 and Qt 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858868/serious-rendering-issues-with-opengl-4-1-and-qt-5)

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes it is a duplicate of the issue you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue after my update.
Things I did were:

- remove all comment BEFORE the version definition.
- remove all empty lines AND space before version definition.
- Rebuilt everything, even your resources file.

Looks like Qt made the shadder compiler way more picky!

Comment: It indeed seem to work if I remove the comments before the #version directive. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of Qt 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.4.0 5.4.1 5.4.2 for  NVIDIA drivers 347+ ,
It will fix in Qt5.5.
See the link [QTBUG 44968](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44968)