# QOpenGLShader - version directive must be first statement and may not be repeated

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I'am building an OpenGL-application using Qt 5.11.2. When adding a tessellation shader the following error occurs:

> QOpenGLShader::compile(Tessellation Control): 0(2) : error C0204: version directive must be first statement and may not be repeated

```
*** Problematic Tessellation Control shader source code ***
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
#line 1
´╗┐#version 400
#line 1
layout (vertices = 4) out;
```

I'm working on Windows 10 with Geforce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 GPU.

I've found similar reports, but none of the answers worked for me: [unable to compile GLSL shaders on Qt 5.3 after Nvidia driver update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417882/unable-to-compile-glsl-shaders-on-qt-5-3-after-nvidia-driver-update)

[Serious rendering issues with OpenGL 4.1 and Qt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858868/serious-rendering-issues-with-opengl-4-1-and-qt-5)

The shader looks like this:

```
#version 400
layout (vertices = 4) out;

uniform float animationFrame;
in vec3 v_vertex[];

out vec3 tc_vertex[];

void main()
{...}
```

To add the shader I use the following code:

```
addShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "data/cube.vert", *m_program);
addShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "data/cube.frag", *m_program);
addShader(QOpenGLShader::TessellationControl, "data/cube.tcs", *m_program);
addShader(QOpenGLShader::TessellationEvaluation, "data/cube.tes", *m_program);
addShader(QOpenGLShader::Geometry, "data/cube.geom", *m_program);
```

Obviously the first lines inserted by Qt produce the error. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the `´╗┐` in `´╗┐#version 400`? Copy/paste error? Passing a `std::string` where a `const char*` is expected? May be, you should also show the code how you load the shader text in C++.

Comment: Couldn't you drop the `#version 400` completely? I found [SO: Qt5 OpenGL GLSL version error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33482388/7478597) which reflects what I was already thinking.

Comment: I added the code I use for shader loading. I also thought about an copy/paste error, but the ```´╗┐``` is still shown in the error message after retyping the line.

Comment: Concerning the `´╗┐`: It might be an artefact from text editor where you wrote your shader codes in e.g. a BOM if your text editor used UTF-8 encoding. Shader code should be stored in ASCII without any BOM or such things... (But it's just a guess. You could use a hex-dump to check whether I was right.)

Comment: @HerthaBSC: That's not shader loading code. That's the code which tells something else to load the shader.

Comment: @Scheff The problem was indeed caused by the editor. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I have the error like this:

```
???#version 330 core
```

I use visual code to change the file encoding from "utf-8 with BOM" to "utf-8". Then it works.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, my errors shows like this:

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): 0(2) : error C0204: version directive must be first statement and may not be repeated

*** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
#ifdef GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
#extension GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions : enable
#extension GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced : enable
#endif
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
#line 1
???#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main(void)
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}

***
```

as you can see, there are `???` in the messages, while you have `´╗┐`

when I changed from "utf-8 with BOM" to "utf-8", it works~

Answer (score -1):

I guess the answer is  "version directive must be first statement and may not be repeated"

So, put your version directive to the first line - before all defines and the same.
Just checked it - that is it.
When I put directive "#version 330 core" in the fourth line of code - the same error "version directive must be first statement and may not be repeated" occured;
So the right way is to put this directive to the first line as it should be:

```
1 #version 330 core
2 in highp vec3 vert;
3 in highp vec3 vertNormal;
```

Where 1,2,3 - line's numbers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).